# How to Request User Data after Logged In, Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js, passport.js

Hello guys I'm new to Node so please bear with me.

Anyway I am currently working on authentication for my new Node app. So far I was capable of getting everything basic working (login, register, logout). I am now entering the settings page of my user profile but I cannot access {{username}} or {{email}} for example, it either stays blank or throws back an error.

I was wondering how I can make the username, email and other info stay in the session or able to access it once my user is logged in, and how I can add more information to the session later (this is important as I will need to do it).

Here is my code:

Registration (not including verification)

```
    var newUser = new User({
            username: username,
            email:email,
            password: password
        });

User.createUser(newUser, function(err, user){
            if(err) throw err;
            console.log(user);
            req.flash('success_msg', 'You are registered and can now login');
```

Login:

```
router.post('/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {successRedirect:'/', failureRedirect:'/users/login',failureFlash: true}),
  function(req, res) {
    res.redirect('/');
  });
```

I'm not sure exactly what code I need to show but if you guys need to see anything else to help me please let me know.

I'm using Node.JS with express, passport and handlebars.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was wondering how I can make the username, email and other info stay
>   in the session or able to access it once my user is logged in, and how
>   I can add more information to the session later (this is important as
>   I will need to do it).

There is a pretty good NPM module for this use case :

https://github.com/expressjs/session

I have made quite good experiences with it.

Just install it via NPM and then :

```
var session = require('express-session')
```

This is how you use it:

```
// Use the session middleware
app.use(session({ secret: 'keyboard cat', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }}))

// Access the session as req.session
app.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.session.views) {
    req.session.views++
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html')
    res.write('<p>views: ' + req.session.views + '</p>')
    res.write('<p>expires in: ' + (req.session.cookie.maxAge / 1000) + 's</p>')
    res.end()
  } else {
    req.session.views = 1
    res.end('welcome to the session demo. refresh!')
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you, I can see that your example is working. I was wondering how I could implement it into saving session variables such as username, etc, in another file. Like how would I add username to the session is users.js for example?

Comment: You can save anything you want to your session/cookie. What you usually want to do, is associate your username with the cookie id.

Comment: I'm sorry to keep asking questions but I'm really lost. How would I go about doing that? If I try to use lets say req.session.user or username it tells me that req is undifined. I don't know if I have to re-initiate the session or how to go about adding the username and email to the session once the user logs in... Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is going a bit to far for me. I'll gladly point you in the right direction 
though. Have a look here https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/ and here https://www.tutorialspoint.com/expressjs/expressjs_sessions.htm and here https://lockmedown.com/securing-node-js-managing-sessions-express-js/

Answer (score 1):

As i am getting from your description is that you have problem regarding sessions.
for this you can visit https://www.npmjs.com/package/session-storage to Include session-storage into your project it will help you better.